# Is any way to store form data without using database?

Tags: angularjs, database

I am developing a registration application where registration details will be saved and at the time of login as per the user's registration details, the output will be displayed. So first we have to store the registration details into the database and at the time of login, the details of the user will come from the database after running some business logic.

Is there any way to store the data without using the database?
OR
In this context how AngularJs can help me? Please explain to me I am a newbie to application development.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly ways of storing info, you could use PHP to write it to a document but the reason we have databases is because they are the most efficient way.

SQL isn't difficult to learn and there are plenty of libraries that make it easy to write to from web apps.

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql